# Yii Default Controller and Trying to Find matching controller route first?

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

Say I have 3 Controllers `ShareController`, `IndexController` and `AjaxController`

I set the `IndexController` as the `DefaultController`. But I would like `/share` to show the `Index` Action of `Share` instead of trying to find the `share` Action of `IndexController`

My current urlManager:

```
'rules'=>array(
          '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
          '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule inside your url-manager rules:

```
"share" => "share/index"
```